# Add multiple callback responses to array

Tags: javascript

I have this multiple function called `checkForURLS` that calls another two functions that return callbacks, how can I add to the array once both callbacks have returned and then return the array as a callback? I'm working with pure JavaScript.

```
function checkForURLs(uniqueURL, customURL, callback) {
    var errors = [];

    checkForUniqueURL(uniqueURL, function(UniqueURLCallback) {
        if (UniqueURLCallback===true) {
            errors.push("This unique URL is already taken, please try another.");
        }
    });

    if (customURL.length>0) {
        checkForCustomURL(customURL, function(customURLCallback) {
            if (customURLCallback===true) {
                errors.push("This custom URL is already taken, please try another.");
            }
        });
    }

    if (errors.length>0) {
        return callback(errors);
    } else {
        return callback(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should be working. You call ```checkForURLs(urlA, urlB, function(error) { /* handle your error in the callback function */ });```. Isn't that, what you want? What do you want?

Comment: It seems to be coming back empty, but if I put a callback in one of the inner callbacks to return the callback(errors), it works but just for that particular callback. What's happening is the if statement isn't waiting and just returning instantly. With jQuery I could have used something like 'done' and then returned but not sure how to in JavaScript.

Comment: sounds like `checkForUniqueURL()` does something asynchronous and all this should be done using promises. Show all relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise` constructor `new Promise(function)`, `Promise.all()` to perform task when `checkForUniqueURL` and `checkForCustomURL` callbacks have been called.

```js
function callback(value) {
  return value
}

function checkForUniqueURL(url, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(callback(true))
    }, Math.random() * 1500)
  })
}

function checkForCustomURL(url, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(callback(true))
    }, Math.random() * 1500)
  })
}

function checkForURLs(uniqueURL, customURL, callback) {
  var errors = [];

  return Promise.all([
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      checkForUniqueURL(uniqueURL, function(UniqueURLCallback) {
        if (UniqueURLCallback === true) {
          errors.push("This unique URL is already taken, please try another.");
        } 
        resolve()
      })
    })
  , new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (customURL.length > 0) {
        checkForCustomURL(customURL, function(customURLCallback) {
          if (customURLCallback === true) {
            errors.push("This custom URL is already taken, please try another.");
          }
          resolve()
        });
      }
    })
  ])
  .then(function() {
    console.log(errors);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(callback(errors));
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(callback(new Error("false")));
    }
  })
}

checkForURLs("abc", "def", callback)
  .then(function(errs) {
    console.log(errs);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("err:", err.message)
  })
```

Comment: @PaulNess See updated post. Adjusted `resolve()` to outside of `if`` statement. Previously, if `errors.length > 0` was `false` `reject()` would not be called.

Answer (score 0):

If all functions you use are synchronous and are implemented similar to the following, you code works perfectly well:

```js
function checkForURLs(uniqueURL, customURL, callback) {
    var errors = [];

    checkForUniqueURL(uniqueURL, function(UniqueURLCallback) {
        if (UniqueURLCallback===true) {
            errors.push("This unique URL is already taken, please try another.");
        }
    });

    if (customURL.length>0) {
        checkForCustomURL(customURL, function(customURLCallback) {
            if (customURLCallback===true) {
                errors.push("This custom URL is already taken, please try another.");
            }
        });
    }

    if (errors.length>0) {
        return callback(errors);
    } else {
        return callback(false);
    }
}

// Just test-implement those two functions:
function checkForUniqueURL(url, callback) { callback(true); }
function checkForCustomURL(url, callback) { callback(true); }


errors = checkForURLs("test", "test2", function(errors) {
  console.log(errors);
  return "I have got some errors!";
});

console.log(errors);
```

If indeed your code has asynchronous parts, you would need to "wait" with the `return callback()` until those are finished. Maybe by wrapping them in another callback?

Answer (score 0):

This will work IFF your `checkForUniqueURL` and `checkForCustomURL` functions are synchronous. Here is an example of it **working** with **synchronous** functions...

https://jsfiddle.net/ojh5b1f8/

However, I'm going to assume, since its not working, that your functions are asynchronous. Here is an example of it **not working** with **asynchronous** functions...

https://jsfiddle.net/uzjbyrt7/

It doesn't work, because the `checkForURLs` function returns before the callbacks are fired. The best solution in this case, is [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). However, you will likely need to use a library to get promise support, since they are not yet implemented in all browsers. I recommend [bluebird.js](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). Here is an example of it working with asynchronous functions and promises...

https://jsfiddle.net/ynxcu7t6/